# _tikapi.default.onLogin is not a function in React

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, next.js

So I am trying to authenticate users through TikApi(Tiktok unofficial API) in my react application.

There are clear steps provided here https://github.com/tikapi-io/login-popup.

Here are the steps given in the above GitHub link.

Step 1. `You can open the OAuth window by calling the function like this:`

```
TikAPI.popup({
    client_id: "c_1234567890",
    //scope: ['VIEW_PROFILE', 'USER_MESSAGES'], (optional)
});
```

Step 2. `Now you're all set, you can now listen to user login events and get the user info like this`

```
TikAPI.onLogin(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

A successful example

```
{
    access_token: "C5BGTXRtQs7jiy4CNURuwLXbDxRl2VIk"
    client_id: "c_1234567890"
    message: "Authorization has been completed successfully."
    scope: ["VIEW_PROFILE"]
    state: undefined
    type: "success"
    userInfo: {
        avatar: "https://uploads.tikapi.io/avatars/c8f3f02070fc613e0b663b2d33b366f9.jpeg?v=1606338347"
        birthday: ""
        followers_count: 0
        followings_count: 0
        gender: 0
        id: "6845742198232105989"
        nickname: "user9155470419087"
        sec_user_id: "MS4wLjABAAAA77cXhkB15fV7rqAAMI0zGK_R1OaW8NjnVoO8ZIg8qfUm0d_XUs31QqEql3WVsDc8"
        user_verified: false
        username: "demoapi"
    }
}
```

But Unfortunately, I missed something that I got `_tikapi.default.onLogin is not a function`[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-chaum-0lpjxl?file=/src/App.js) of my code.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't loaded the Login Popup script.

You should remove this line:

```
import TikAPI from "tikapi"
```

Because that package is only for the calling the API in Node.js.

Instead, edit your index.html on your react app and add this before the end of the body:

```
<script src="https://tikapi.io/assets/js/popup.js"></script>
```